# How to Integrate Help file (.chm) with Web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, chm

I want to integrate Help File (.chm) with my web application developed in ASP.Net with C#. Actually, I get to open the chm file using javascript 'ShowHelp' function. But I wanna give context wise Help functionality.

I mean, if User is on Customer registration page and clicks on help icon, then according help page should open in chm file.

Can anybody please guide me on this?

Comment: Are you sure that it has to be a `.chm` file? Chm is a compiled html file, intended for offline (desktop) usage. There is no point in forcing user to download the entire compiled file when he/she is online and has access to individual help pages. Not to mention that versioning and updates are much simpler if you keep help online.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to create a htm page for help and every individual page you just call this htm page using #AnchorName. Please visit this [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html)

Answer (score 0):

Build your help web pages using screwTurn wiki and then add reference to each page on the respective asp.net pages.

http://www.screwturn.eu/